# Inclusions in Source Code are unresolved

Tags: c++, eclipse, gtk

I am using Eclipse (Windows XP) and using the option "new makefile project from Existing code". I import the source code and everything looks alright, except these three imports remain unresolved:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <glib/gi18n.h>
```

I have downloaded GTK3.6.4 and set its bin directory [AND /include/ directory] as a PATH environment variable. (GTK did not have an installation process, I just extracted it from .zip) How can I fix these inclusions?

I have been playing around with the Paths & Symbols settings and the PATH environment variable but nothing is working. Is it perhaps possible that I would need an older version of GTK?

Comment: you added the include directory to the PATH variable? You need to add them to the compiler, probably something like `gcc -Ic:\path\to\gtk\include ...`.

Comment: @m.s. That sounds like what I'm looking for, but I don't know how to add them to the compiler. I enter `gcc -I<path to include directory>` and it always says fatal error: no input files 
I've tried a path to the exact file and directories but nothing works

Comment: you need to add this directory to the call of your compiler in your makefile

Comment: @m.s. honestly i have no idea how to do that, could you give me an example of the syntax you would use? I have very little understand of C/C++, ive only just started

Comment: Show the Makefile you are using-.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have the Gtk bin directory in your PATH env vas, try to run

```
pkg-config --cflags gtk+3.0
pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0
```

and put the output of the first command to the compiler flags somewhere in eclipses build settings (sorry I do not use eclipse) And the output of the second command in the linker options flags.

If the command pront fail to find the pkg-config program check that it's path is in %path%.